# How to convert datetime format in 24 hour datetime format in Excel

Tags: excel, date, time, format

I have few assignment details with system date as in format: 27/1/2020 10:01 PM. I want to convert it into 1/27/2020 22:01 in MS-Excel.

I tried extracting dates using INT function and time separate and later concatenate but it shows error. Also, tried changing the date format using custom but not working.

Any ideas?

Comment: Required time format: 1/27/2020 22:01

Comment: Have you tried format `m/dd/yyyy h:mm`?

Comment: Yes, tried already. Not working.

Comment: If it is not working means the underlying data is in text format. Quick way to check this is if default alignment is used then all text data will be left aligned and all numerical data will be right aligned.

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij could be right. IF the dates are stored as text, first you need to convert them into numbers (Dates are numbers actually). Have you tried using a helper column and something like `=VALUE(A1)` and then apply desired format into that new column?

Comment: I checked the default alignment as well. It's numerical. The problem is it is not responding to any of the formula. Not sure what could be the issue here. Error comes up #VALUE

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your data is consistent as shown in sample and it is in cell `A1` you can try below formula which will convert it to logical date and time.

`=DATE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/"," ")," ",REPT(" ",99)),2*99,99))*1,TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",REPT(" ",99)),1*99,99))*1,LEFT(A1,FIND("/",A1,1)-1)*1)+TIMEVALUE(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1,1)+1,99))`

And then apply the custom formatting `m/dd/yyyy h:mm`.